# How to add image on canvas with fabric

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

This is my first time using fabric.js.
I want to add a picture on canvas but it doesn't work

this is my html

```
<canvas id="workCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index:0; top:10%; left:10%"></canvas>
```

and this is js

```
function imageOnCanvas() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('#workCanvas')

    fabric.Image.fromURL("image/flower.jfif",function(myImg) {
        console.log(myImg);
        canvas.add(myImg);
    })
}
```

Comment: Please check the console log error

Comment: there are no error...

Comment: Did you call your function ```imageOnCanvas();```?

Comment: $(function() {
imageOnCanvas();
})
is on top of code. is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a `id` directly in the `new fabric.Canvas("workCanvas");`

Ref. http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#why_fabric

```js
function imageOnCanvas() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("workCanvas");

  fabric.Image.fromURL(
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Example_image.svg/600px-Example_image.svg.png",
    function (myImg, err) {
      canvas.add(myImg);
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}

imageOnCanvas();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="workCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index:0; top:10%; left:10%"></canvas>
```

Comment: This code work in different place but doesn't work in my code. maybe my other codes are problem thank you :)

Comment: @ResetMara, try to ```console.log(err)``` like the way I do to see the error message.